# TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'list'` in python

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

```
def sentiment(text)
    ................//some code   
    pos=round(pos,3)
    neu=round(neu,3)
    neg=round(neg,3)

    result={'pos':[pos] , 'neg':[neg],'neu':[neu] }
    return result    

count=0;

f1 = open('testData.txt')

sentence= f1.readline()

result={'pos':[] , 'neg':[],'neu':[] }

for sentence in f1:
    vs =sentiment(sentence)
    result['pos'].append(vs['pos'])
    result['neg'].append(vs['neg'])
    result['neu'].append(vs['neu'])
    sentence=f1.readline()
    print ('sum:')

for i in result.keys():
    print ('\t',i, '=>', sum(result[i]))
```

I got an error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\DIl\Desktop\MYChoi\lex\sentiment_lexian.py", line 305, in <module>
    print ('\t',i, '=>', sum(result[i]))
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'list'
```

Comment: What is your question?

Answer (score 0):

The default for `sum()` is `0` -- it's meant for adding up numbers.  However, you have given it a `list` of `list`s instead:

```
# 'pos' maps to a list with a single number in it
result = {'pos':[pos], 'neg':[neg], 'neu':[neu]}

# everytime this runs, 'pos' gets a new list
result['pos'].append(vs['pos'])

# i == 'pos'
# result[i] == [[0.827], [0.273], [0.111]] (for example)
for i in result.keys():
    print ('\t',i, '=>', sum(result[i]))
```

If you change the line in `sentiment` from

```
result = {'pos':[pos], 'neg':[neg], 'neu':[neu]}
```

to

```
result = {'pos':pos, 'neg':neg, 'neu':neu}
```

then that should do what you want, if `pos`, `neg`, and `neu` are single numbers.

Comment: can yu explain a code ,if i want to get very positive and positive clear from 'pos' value,how i could do using result.keys?  (after yr answer step)                       ex:  from  result['pos'] how can i get Very positive -0.5-1 range                                                                           Positive 0-0.5 using if condition?